# Number of subscribers to an MQTT brokers to get all messages

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm running mosquttio as an MQTT broker and I have multiple devices sending sensory data periodically. I want to collect all the messages and store them. My question is, is there any advantage to having multiple connections (each connection has a unique id and subscribed to subset of the topics.) to the broker or is it preferable to have a single connection gathering all the data.

Note: the subscribers will be on the same machine as the broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably depends on the messages in question and what processing the client is going to do on those messages.

Having a single client subscribed to '#' will mean that there will only be a single entry on the subscribed topic to search for matches when processing a message. But this is probably a negligible amount of overhead under most situations.

If the message rate is high enough and there is any overhead to the storage then using something called Shared Subscriptions to allow a pool of client to all subscribe to the same topic (or wildcard) and ensure that any message is only delivered to a single client in the pool. This means that the processing of messages can be load balanced over the pool of clients.

Using Shared Subscriptions means that you can dynamically add or remove clients from the pool without having to repartition the topic space across the clients.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of shared subscriptions. I have another question, if I care about storing the data in the order they were generated, would using shared subscriptions be a good idea? In my mind, on subscriber can receive msg_1 and another receive msg_2 from the same topic, but the msg_2 is processed faster and inserted before msg_1, effectively messing up the order.

Comment: Once you have multiple clients, maintaing order in the back end storage is always going to be a challenge, there is nothing on the MQTT sides that can help with that